# How To MultiThread A Task With Queue Being A List Of Tupples Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I Have 2 Code That Preferred To Have Faster Processing

## First Code

( On My Recent Thread Someone Pointed Out That My Threading Code Is Wrong )

He Stated That No Matter The Value Of TotalThread It Won't Process Faster

```
class ThreadingPower(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue= queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            Manager = self.queue.get()
            for Numbers,HWID in Manager:
                r = requests.post(URL, data=payload) # License Checker Required Numbers ( Buyer Code ) And HWID ( License Code )
                data = (r.text)
                if ('Verified' in data):
                    with open(resultsFile,'a+') as results: 
                        results.write("The Number : "+str(Numbers)+" Is Verified By The "+str(HWID))
                    results.close()
                    print str(HWID)+" Is Server Verified"
                else:
                    print str(HWID)+" Is Not Server Verified"
            self.queue.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(TotalThread):
        t = ThreadingPower(queue)
        t.setDaemon(False)
        t.start()

    queue.put(credentials)
    queue.join()
```

The Credentials Are Tupples

```
[
 ['UniqueHWID', 'BuyerCode'], 
 ['UniqueHWID', 'BuyerCode'], 
 ['UniqueHWID', 'BuyerCode']
]
```

## The Second Code

```
class ThreadingPower(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue= queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            Performance = self.queue.get()
            for Name,ScoreA,ScoreB,ScoreC in Performance:
                TScore = (ScoreA+ScoreB+ScoreC)/3
                print Name+" Has Scored :"+TScore
                if (TScore >= PassScore):
                    print Name+" Has Passed"
                    # Sending Message To The Server With Name Has Pass
                else:
                    print Name+" Has Failed"
                    # Sending Message To The Server With Name Has Failed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(TotalThread):
        t = ThreadingPower(queue)
        t.setDaemon(False)
        t.start()

    queue.put(TestSheet)
    queue.join()
```

With TestSheet Looking Like This

```
[
 ['StudentName', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'], 
 ['StudentName', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'], 
 ['StudentName', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
]
```

I'm Still Learning A Few About Python,Sorry For Asking So Much Question
I Haven't Test The Second Code But Since The Threading Part Is Base From The First Code I Think It Has The Same Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go one Step back, try first without `threading`**.

```
def run(p):
    Performance = p
    Name, ScoreA, ScoreB, ScoreC = Performance

    TScore = int((ScoreA + ScoreB + ScoreC) / 3)
    print('{} Has Scored:{}'.format(Name, TScore))

    if TScore >= PassScore:
        print(Name + " Has Passed")
    else:
        print(Name + " Has Failed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PassScore = 10
    #              Name         ScoreA, ScoreB, ScoreC
    TestSheet = [['StudentName1', 1,       2,     3],
                 ['StudentName2', 4, 5, 6],
                 ['StudentName3', 7, 8, 9]]
    for p in TestSheet:
        run(p)
```

If the result met your needs, add `threading`.

```
class ThreadingPower(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        Performance = self.queue.get()
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    for p in TestSheet:
        queue.put(p)
    ...
```

---

> **Question**:  He Stated That No Matter The Value Of TotalThread It Won't Process Faster

What you are doing is,

1. Starting **n** Threads
2. All Threads waiting at `queue.get()`
3. Put **ONE** Message into the Queue
4. Only **ONE** Thread can get this Message and have to do **ALL** the jobs.

Change your code to `put` the 3 jobs from your `TestSheet` **one** after the other.

```
for job in TestSheet:
    queue.put(job)
```

This is invalid Python, you have to change this to your **new** `queue` Data:

```
for in Name,ScoreA,ScoreB,ScoreC in Performance:
```

Second, you puting a List of `str` into the `queue` and want to do some math, this will **FAIL** also!

Comment: I Don't Know How

Comment: So The Jobs Are The TestSheets ?,for Name,ScoreA,ScoreB,ScoreC in TestSheet : queue.put(Name) queue.put(ScoreA) queue.put(ScoreB) queue.put(ScoreC) ,I Don't UnderStand How This Would Work Do I Then self.queue.get() 4 Times Then Perform For Name,ScoreA,ScoreB,ScoreC in Performance:#Do Something Here ?

Comment: @David: No, `Name, Score...` are Values of **one** Job. One Job is the List of Values, in your example ` ['StudentName', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']`. Your `TestSheet` holds **3** Jobs. Read this and follow the examples [Python Multithreaded Programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)